# Finding $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that $(4, -3, 1, 7) + 2x = (5, 9, -6, 8)$ using elementary row operations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am going through some linear algebra problems for revision.

I am told to find $x \in \mathbb{R}^4$ such that

$$(4, -3, 1, 7) + 2x = (5, 9, -6, 8).$$

From what I remember, I would solve these types of problems using matrices and elementary row operations to get them into reduced row echelon form. For illustration, something like

$$\begin{align}
& \left[\begin{array}{cccc|ccc} 0 & 1 & -2 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & -2 & 4 & 10 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \end{array}\right] \end{align}$$

But, from what I remember, this might only be possible for systems of linear equations of the form $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, and my problem may not be able to be put into this form.

Anyway, is it possible to solve this problem using this method (some kind of matrix computation method)? If so, how do I go about it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $a+2x=b$ where $a$ and $b$ are vectors, you can solve it directly. $$x=\frac{b-a}{2}.$$

You can also view it as $Ix=\frac{b-a}{2}$ and it is already in reduced row echelon form.

The augmented matrix that you show us is a typical starting point to find a matrix inverse.

Comment: Hmm, isn't this method also used to solve $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$ (from what I remember)?

Comment: From your augmented matrix, where do you place your $b$?

Comment: Maybe the method didn't use the augmented matrix, but from what I remember there was some matrix computation method to solve $\mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$, no?

Comment: You can augment $[A|b]$ and obtain the RREF if you want as shown in $Ix=\frac{b-a}{2}$ and the augmented matrix is $[I|\frac{b-a}{2}]$. But for this problem, I don't think we should go there.

Comment: Ok, now I remember what I'm referring to: It was "LU decomposition" with Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler than what you're proposing. If you have $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, then you can determine each value by comparing the results from the equation for each coordinate, namely you have

$$4 + 2x_1 = 5 \implies x_1 = \frac{1}{2} \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$-3 + 2x_2 = 9 \implies x_2 = 6 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$1 + 2x_3 = -6 \implies x_3 = \frac{-7}{2} \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

$$7 + 2x_4 = 8 \implies x_4 = \frac{1}{2} \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

Thus, you have $x = \left(\frac{1}{2}, 6, \frac{-7}{2}, \frac{1}{2}\right)$.

Comment: I know that it can be done more simply by direct computation, but I wanted to recall/apply the matrix computation method for my own revision.

Comment: @DomFomello Thanks for letting me know. I'm sorry for misunderstanding your question. As it doesn't answer what you're asking about, I'll be deleting my answer in a short while.

Comment: Please don't! It's an informative addition to the thread.

Comment: @DomFomello All right, as you request, I'll leave it then.